# Checking if authenticated in Django template inheritance 

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in a template and am having difficulty showing when a user is logged in. I will be able to login, but when I revisit the page, it shows that I'm still not authenticated.

```
  {% extends "base.html" %}

{% load catalog_tags %}
{% block site_wrapper %}
<div id = "main">
  <a href="#content" class="skip_link">Skip to main content</a>
  <div id = "banner">
    <div class="bannerIEPadder">
      <div class="cart_box">
    {% cart_box request %}
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:right;">[search box goes here]</div>
  <div id="navigation">
    <div class="navIEPadder">
      <!--navigation tabs at the top of each page -->
      {% comment %}{% include "tags/navigation.html" %} {% endcomment %}
      {% category_list request.path %}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <!--<div class="sidebarIEPadder">[search box goes here]</br>
    {% comment %}{% category_list request.path %}{% endcomment %}
      </div>-->
    </div>
    <div id="content">
<!--      <a name = "content"></a>-->
      <div class="contentIEPadder">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <div class="footerIEPadder">
      {% footer_links %}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And here's the file it references. Since this will be an extension of all templates, is there something I need to consider?

```
###category_list.html
<!--<h3>Categories</h3>-->

<!--<ul id="categories">-->
<ul>
  {% with active_categories as cats %}
  {% for c in cats %}
  <li> 
    {% comment %}
    {% ifequal c.get_absolute_url request_path %}
    {{c.name}}
    {% else %}
    {% endcomment %}
    <div><a href="{{c.get_absolute_url}}" class="category">{{c.name}}</a></div>
    {% comment %}{% endifequal %}{% endcomment %}
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
  <div class="fr">
    <ul>
      <li>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href = "{% url django.contrib.auth.views.logout %}">Logout</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href = "{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">Login</a>
    {% endif %}
      </li>
  </div>
{% endwith %}


</ul>

<div class="cb"></div>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.py?

Comment: Where does the "user" object come from?  Can you include the view function that makes this available to the page?  Are you using the session middleware correctly?

Comment: @danihp yes it is there.

Comment: @S.Lott this will be shown on every page

Comment: Ok, then is that you are not sending request in some views. Remember to include requestContext rendering all templates. I send to you a link, below, in my answer. Also check that sessions are enabled: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES should contains 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'

Comment: Expanding on @S.Lott's comment, should you not instead be using `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` in your template?

Comment: No that's not it. I think it has something to do with how one file is being used in another. For example if I insert {{user.is_authenticated}} into the main file I get returned true. But once I putti in category_list.html it returns false

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a RequestContext to the template. The easiest way to do this is to import django.shortcuts and use the render method in your view:

```
return render(request, "my_template.html")
```

Comment: I am passing a context to the template, but it doesn't seem to apply to the request.path

Answer (score 1):

- Is django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting.py?
- Do you use [requestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) rendering template?
- Check that sessions are enabled: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES should contains 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'

Comment: I am using the requestContext rendering template and also set the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS